# How to break line after matching case but needs to go back a couple of characters

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting, gawk

I have the following sample:

```
1. TNT 00:00 2. Swing From The Gutters 7:34 3. Ten-Day Interval 13:29 4. I Set My Face To The Hillside 18:16 5. The Equator 24:26 6. A Simple Way To Go Faster Than Light That Does Not Work 28:27 7. The Suspension Bridge At Iguazu Falls 32:03 8. Four-Day Interval 37:42 9. In Sarah, Mencken, Christ And Beethoven There Were Women And Men 42:29 10. Almost Always Is Nearly Enough 50:01 11. Jetty 52:45 12. Everglade 1:01:09 1:05:32
```

Which I want to convert into:

```
1. TNT 00:00 
2. Swing From The Gutters 7:34 
3. Ten-Day Interval 13:29 
4. I Set My Face To The Hillside 18:16 
5. The Equator 24:26 
6. A Simple Way To Go Faster Than Light That Does Not Work 28:27 
7. The Suspension Bridge At Iguazu Falls 32:03 
8. Four-Day Interval 37:42 
9. In Sarah, Mencken, Christ And Beethoven There Were Women And Men 42:29 
10. Almost Always Is Nearly Enough 50:01 
11. Jetty 52:45 
12. Everglade 1:01:09 1:05:32
```

The logical path I was following is that I know there will always be a "dot" (.) that comes with the number of the track and I can use it as a guideline for the breaks. The trouble is, it has to crawl back one or two characters in order to keep the number of the tracks.

Answer (score 4):

At least with GNU sed, you can insert a newline before all but the first matching sequence using a `2g` modifier:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]+\./\n&/2g' file
```

Comment: The `Ng` means "replace globally but start at the Nth occurrence", right?

Comment: @terdon yes that's right - or as the manual puts it, "ignore matches before the *numberth*, and then match and replace all matches from the *numberth* on"

Answer (score 4):

Just capture the number and the dot and insert a newline before them:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\s(\d+\.)/\n$1/g' file 
1. TNT 00:00 
2. Swing From The Gutters 7:34 
3. Ten-Day Interval 13:29 
4. I Set My Face To The Hillside 18:16 
5. The Equator 24:26 
6. A Simple Way To Go Faster Than Light That Does Not Work 28:27 
7. The Suspension Bridge At Iguazu Falls 32:03 
8. Four-Day Interval 37:42 
9. In Sarah, Mencken, Christ And Beethoven There Were Women And Men 42:29 
10. Almost Always Is Nearly Enough 50:01 
11. Jetty 52:45 
12. Everglade 1:01:09 1:05:32
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that both answers on this question came in: (a) 10.5 minutes after it was asked, and more amazingly, (b) 15 seconds apart. (**#TooSlow**, @terdon! )

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk` or `mawk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='[0-9]+\\.' 'NR > 1 { print NR-1 ".", $0 }' file
1.  TNT 00:00
2.  Swing From The Gutters 7:34
3.  Ten-Day Interval 13:29
4.  I Set My Face To The Hillside 18:16
5.  The Equator 24:26
6.  A Simple Way To Go Faster Than Light That Does Not Work 28:27
7.  The Suspension Bridge At Iguazu Falls 32:03
8.  Four-Day Interval 37:42
9.  In Sarah, Mencken, Christ And Beethoven There Were Women And Men 42:29
10.  Almost Always Is Nearly Enough 50:01
11.  Jetty 52:45
12.  Everglade 1:01:09 1:05:32
```

The `awk` code reads the line as a set of records separated by a positive integer and a dot (`[0-9]+\.`).  The body of the code simply prints the current record number (minus one, as the first record is the empty one before the initial `1.`), a dot, and then the rest of the record.

Answer (score 0):

A masochistic GNU grep solution

```
grep -oP '\d+[.]((?!\d+[.]).)+(?=\h)' file
```